# A very large computer case

Tags: case, video-adapters

So, now I have HAF X case, ASUS Rampage IV, and a 1080Ti video card.

All fine and well, except I can't fit the video card into the second x16 PCI slot because of the case back panel hinge. So I need another computer case, however, I don't know which to buy: it seems impossible to say in advance if a case would fit all the hardware. All the "large" cases I was able to find are basically the same size as HAF X.

So the question is -- are there substantially larger computer cases in the market? If yes, how do I find them?

Comment: I'd like to know more, or even see a picture, of what your exact issue is and what you require.

Comment: If you know all of your specs, you could try entering them on [pc part picker](https://pcpartpicker.com/). It will filter out pc cases for you. That way you wouldn't need to brute force buy an inordinately large case.